# Transfor list items into dict keys with a default value

Tags: python

I have a list of strings of the type `cities=['Los Angeles', 'Cancun', 'Paris']`, and I want to generate a dict with a key for each item in the list, and an empty array as value, like this:

```
cities_dict ={
    'Los Angeles': [],
    'Cancun': [],
    'Paris': []
}
```

I tried this `dict(([city.name], []) for city in cities))`, but I get a syntax error.

Is there any way I can get this dict without traversing list item by item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Python versions have [`dict` comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays), so you can do this:

```
{city: [] for city in cities}
```

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot